# Pandas Find Date Frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset:

```
    login                 id
0   2015-06-22 04:55:00   1
1   2015-06-23 05:55:00   1
2   2015-06-25 04:55:00   2
3   2015-06-26 02:55:00   2
4   2015-07-02 04:55:00   2
5   2015-07-12 04:55:00   3
6   2015-07-13 04:55:00   3
7   2015-07-15 04:55:00   5
8   2015-07-21 04:55:00   5
9   2015-07-22 04:55:00   5
10  2015-07-30 04:55:00   5
11  2015-08-30 04:55:00   5
12  2015-06-02 04:55:00   7
13  2015-07-02 04:55:00   7
14  2015-08-02 04:55:00   7
```

I am using Pandas in Python for the analysis. I would like to check if a particular id has logged in at least 2 times in a 24 hour period, and store those ids in a list called good_id.

For example: 
id = 1 would not be stored because they logged in twice but in a 25 hour period. 
id = 2 would be stored because they have.

etc.

Comment: The question is not clear, id 2 logged in on 6-25 then 6-30 and then 7-02. How is that twice in 24 hour period?

Comment: sorry edited, that 6-30 is now 6-26, and that is within 24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a multiple-step approach:

```
df['last_log'] = df.groupby('id').login.shift().fillna(pd.to_datetime(0))
df['duration'] = df.login - df.last_log

# good ids
df.id[(df['duration'] <= pd.Timedelta(1, 'd'))].unique()

# output: array([2, 3, 5], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Is there a quick way to modify this so we can change the check for the login frequency? Say to store the ids of the users who have logged in 2 times in 3 days, or so.

Comment: change the `1, 'd'` in `pd.Timedelta(1,'d')` to whichever you want, `3,'d'`, `12,'h'`...

Comment: That would give me 1 time in those times, but what about 2 times in x days.

Comment: In that case, put the number of login inside `shift()` in the first command.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are sorting the dataframe by index and then by login.

```
import numpy as np

df.sort_values(by=['id','login'],inplace=True)
df['diff'] = df['login'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1,'h')
```

Comment: This would look at difference of user2's first log in and user1's last log in, etc...

Comment: Groupby is required in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Groupby and diff,

```
df['login'] = pd.to_datetime(df['login'])

df.loc[df.groupby('id')['login'].diff().astype('timedelta64[h]') <= 24, 'id'].unique().tolist()
```

You get

```
[2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Is there a quick way to modify this so we can change the check for the login frequency? Say to store the ids of the users who have logged in 2 times in 3 days, or so.

Comment: df.loc[df.groupby('id')['login'].diff().astype('timedelta64[h]') <= 24 *3] will return the rows if the login occurred in less than or equal to 72 hours. Is that what you want?

Comment: I would like x times in y days. Say to check if a user logged in 15 times in past 120 days or so.